# Routing testing - Location.path() always return empty ""

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular2-testing

I'm following [this tutorial](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/). This is the only modern example I found to test the routing. In time I'd like to use mock components. Sadly, [the delivered plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BXGUZx2nPZWGj1uX40lS?p=preview) does not work.

> Router: App navigate to "" redirects you to /home
>
> Expected '' to be '/home'.

and

> Router: App navigate to "search" takes you to /search
>
> Expected '' to be '/search'.

There is the same issue if I replace:

```
imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)] //by
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
```

Do you guys have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It does not solve the issue. But one workaround is using E2E rather than unit tests.

```
describe('navigation', () => {

  it('root path should redirect to /app', () => {

    browser.get('http://localhost:49152');
    browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) =>
      expect(url).toBe('http://localhost:49152/app')
    );

  });

});
```